# Firebase createUserWithEmailAndPassword is successful, but oncomplete never runs

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

When trying to sign up a new account using firebase, the account is created successfully but the OnCompleteListener never fired, not even the OnFailureListener.

I am trying to do it so that when an account is attempted to be sign in, the system will first check whether or not the account exist, if it does try to sign in, if it doesn't create a new account. When I just use the createUserWithEmailAndPassword a new account is created but my application immediately closed, and the codes under the "OnCompleteListener" or "OnFailureListener" never runs.

I will be able to see the log before these codes and after these codes in the logcat, but none of the log inside these codes are recorded in logcat.

```
auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(mEmail, mPassword)

                    .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()

                    {

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                            // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                            // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(mEmail, mPassword)
                                        .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                                Log.d(TAG, "Start Testing"+task.getException() );

                                                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                                                // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                                                // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                    Log.d(TAG, "Testing Not Success" + task.getException());
                                                    task.getException();

                                                    Log.d(TAG, "Testing Not Success 2" + task.isSuccessful());

                                                }else{
                                                    Log.d(TAG, "Testing is Success" + task.isSuccessful());
                                                    // startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainMenuActivity.class));
                                                    // finish();
                                                }

                                                // ...
                                            }
                                        });
                            }else{
                                Log.w(TAG, "signInCompleted");
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "HI bitch",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                LoginActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainMenuActivity.class));
                                //finish();
                            }

                            // ...
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnFailureListener() {

                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Start Testing"+e );


                }
            });
```

Comment: Update the post if you found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed this, using onSuccessListener instead of onCompleteListener. I assume at this point you either gave up or solved this but i couldn't find an answer anywhere, so the code would be something like this

```
auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(mEmail, mPassword)
          .addOnSuccessListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>(){

                    @Override
                    public void onsuccess(@NonNull AuthResult authResult){
                         //your code goes here
                    }
                 });
```